# Migrate Java EE project to Flex 4

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, flex4, migration

I have a Java EE project which contain a part implemented by Flex.
I want to upgrade all the interfaces, implemented by JSP pages, to
flex 4.
I think that the two technologies are completely different. Also, there
is not a bridge between flex and JSP.
That why i have to reinitialize the project from zero by Flex
technology.
have you any solution please?

Comment: First thought... JSP is a server side technology. A Flex(Flash Builder) application is all client side. Are you separating the server side logic from the presentation information found in the JSP pages? If you currently have a JSP based application, you will still need some sort of server side layer, such as PHP to manage the DB access layer. Having moved from JSP on a Java Enterprise Server to Flex myself, we are currently using, Flex for UI, Doctrine for DB access, and PHP for the server side supporting the Doctrine calls.

Comment: _Hello_
Yes the server side is totally separated : with the spring framework, struts module and hibernate mapping with DB. 
But the initialization, modification and the access to data, of course with the technologies mentioned previously and through javascript code.
And what's I need is to have the same screens implemented with jsp but with flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll attempt to give you a clue where to start. Flex does support using JSP as the backend, using the HTTPService object. Assuming your JSPs were built with this in mind. If not you can build new compliant JSPs that support your existing functionality and the new requirements of an HTTPService call. A decent starting point, provided by Adobe. http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Building_Flex_Applications_with_JSPs-7746.html

The above link assumes you are providing a serializable datastream as the result of a call to your JSP pages. This would allow you to access the data from within your actionscript code, and manipulate it any way you want.

There are other sources available, including BlazeDS, mentioned in the above link. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/blazeds/

Comment: yes this is what i am working about, HTTPService call. it's the solution of James ward
_Thank you anyway_